best way to do a challenge and response that is short and human friendly?
I want to build a challenge and response setup, that is human friendly, so no very large strings that only a computer can process. But also try to keep it secure, so try bring any Hash collisions within something reasonable.
So I was thinking something along the lines of a private/public key. So one person has code they encrypt or sign with the public key, and the private key can decrypt or verify it and provide a response.
Now only the private key can provide a correct response to the challenge, that the public key needs to also verify ( but cant create themselves ).
Now this is possible I know when working with computers, as the sent challenge and responses are large and can be verified easily. But I want to make it human friendly, so someone could provide it over the phone, maybe a 6-8 character string, and the same with the response. And this is without a centralised server or anything.
Would anyone have any suggestions on reading material or anything that could help me find the best way to go about this?
Ideally I would like to write it in javascript, but at this stage I am just trying to figure out the framework of how it can be done.

What do you mean by "human friendly"? Do you mean between two humans each sitting at a computer, or does either or both of them lack a computer? Do they need to communicate in real time with each other and is it over text, phone, in-person?

"encrypt or sign with the public key," no-no-no-no, you sign with your own private key and encrypt with the public key of the other party. If you have an asymmetric scheme it makes sense to use the private key to sign of course, that's usually how (entity-)authentication is performed. Alternatively it is possible to decrypt with the private key and then perform e.g. a MAC calculation with a key derived from the now-shared secret.

TBH, this sounds very much like an X -> Y problem. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want entity authentication or also setup a shared secret, for instance? Challenge response is an end to a means, and I could imagine that there are more appropriate means available.
